# Quem procura, (agora) acha

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto

Uma empresa 100% anglófona que decide se aventurar numa língua nova sabe que vai enfrentar alguns desafios, mas não sabe nem 1/3 de tudo que isso implica. É complicado prever o que vai acontecer num caminho que você nunca trilhou. Nosso sistema nunca precisou levar em consideração certas coisas que são *óbvias* para outras línguas.

O SOpt se depara com diversos desses problemas todo dia, alguns graves, outros não. Alguns consertados, outros ainda não. Já tivemos auto-links que não funcionavam, URLs quebradas e, até esta semana, tínhamos uma busca pra lá de mequetrefe.

## Acentos Aceitos

A busca do SOpt sofria de um problema grave: não tinha suporte completo a acentos. Ou seja, se você procurasse por *"código"*, não encontraria todas as ocorrências de *"codigo"*.

Não interessa o quanto você preze pelo Português bem escrito, deixar de encontrar a resposta que você precisa por conta da teimosia de um computador não deixa ninguém feliz. O site existe para ajudar vocês a encontrarem a solução que procuram e não atingir esse objetivo por conta de um mísero acento agudo era inaceitável.

Então, a partir de hoje, acentos são totalmente bem vindos no site. Uma busca por *"centralização"* vai encontrar *"centralizaçao"*, *"centralizacão"* e *"centralizacao"*. Nunca mais você deixará de encontrar o que procura por conta de um erro de digitacão!

## O que ainda falta

Não sabemos **tudo** que ainda falta. Foi a primeira coisa que eu disse neste post. Mas eis o que já sabemos:

1. A busca com acentos *ainda* não está totalmente pronta. Passei essa semana quase toda ajudando o [Haney](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13244/haney) a regular e ajustar a busca e ainda existem coisas a melhorar. Se encontrarem algo, nos avisem.
2. A busca ainda não compensa diferença na grafia de palavras entre os 2 "Portugueses". Uma busca por "óptimo" não trará resultados com "ótimo". Há uma solução pra isso, e vamos precisar da ajuda de vocês no futuro.
3. Palavras diferentes que significam a mesma coisa são o caso mais difícil do problema acima. Buscas por "abrir ficheiro" trazem 24 resultados, enquanto "abrir arquivo" retorna 217. Isso também tem conserto, e vamos precisar da ajuda de vocês também, mas ficará para o futuro.

## Anedotinha

Nada é tão ruim que não possa piorar. Antes de acharem que nossa busca é ruim, tenham em mente que o nosso [irmão Japonês](http://ja.stackoverflow.com) sequer podia buscar, por conta dos ideogramas.

Programação é difícil.

## Créditos

Agradeçam, principalmente ao [Haney](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13244/haney)! Ele disse que ia dar um jeito e deu!

Comment: Ótima notícia! Tenho certeza que muita gente aqui está disposta a colaborar com o que for necessário para melhorar o sistema ainda mais. Nesse sentido, quanto mais soubermos sobre como funciona, melhor. Então, aguarde: em breve vou cutucar vocês aqui no meta pedindo mais detalhes sobre o sistema de busca :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu estou pensando numa forma de aproximar o site do resto da empresa. Ter apenas a mim como intermediador cria um sentimento de afastamento desta comunidade do resto. Não é verdade do *nosso* lado, mas é verdade do lado de *vocês*. É uma das coisas que quero melhorar este ano.

Comment: Podem contar comigo, posso dar uma ajudinha no pt_PT ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. A ideia é essa mesmo. Mas isso é só num futuro indeterminado. Há bastante a ser feito na busca antes de chegarmos nesse ponto.

Comment: Isso influencia de alguma forma os motores de busca externos (Google) ?

Comment: @gmsantos Não. A indexação do Google é feita à parte e nosso sistema de busca não tem nada a ver com a história.

Comment: `Programação é difícil.` - Que nada, @Gabe, programação é fácil. Dar nomes é difícil. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/it-stack-overflow-update-naming-is-hard/

Comment: @OnoSendai Isso era em 2009. De lá pra cá, programação ficou difícil também :D

Comment: @Gabe uma duvida, a busca por que ignora agora os acentos é feito na camada de aplicação ou na camada do banco?

Answer (score 6):

Obrigado Haney!!

(Gente!! Não acredito que ninguém agradeceu até agora...)

Comment: Ditto. A truckload of thanks to Haney, you cracked the code, mate!